# VBA Macros turning autofill into dates

Tags: vba, excel

So my code is just supposed to autofill Column "H" and "I" with "0" and "1", respectively. It works just as it is supposed to, however for some reason when it gets to a certain section, it turns into dates (e.g. "1/0/1900", "1/1/1900". Not sure why it only does it to certain cells and not others. Here is my code:

```
Sub company()
    With Sheets("Combined")

        .Columns("A:XFD").NumberFormat = "Number"

         LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         .Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Value = 0

        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Value = 1

        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2 = "P"

        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Value2 = 7

        Sheets("Combined").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps format the columns as required first. There may be some errant formatting in sheet.

Comment: @QHarr how would i go about changing the formatting of the sheet

Comment: Something like: Columns("H:I").NumberFormat = "0" You do appear to have a line applying sum formatting at the top? You can add this new line at the start or end perhaps.

Comment: @QHarr that helped! Thank you!

Comment: **Tip**: Instead of `Columns("A:XFD").NumberFormat = ...` you could write `Cells.NumberFormat = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply number formatting to your columns to ensure correct appearance of your numbers e.g.

```
Columns("H:I").NumberFormat = "0"
```